# What does the embedding layer for a network looks like?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, nlp, word-embedding

I just start with text classification, and I got stuck in the embedding layer. If I have a batch of sequences encoded as integer corresponding to each word, what does the embedding layer looks like? Is there neurons like normal neural layer?

I've seen the `keras.layers.Embedding`, but after looking for the document I'm really confused about how does it works. I can understand `input_dim`, but why is `output_dim` a 2D matrix? How many weights do I have in this embedding layer?

I'm sorry if my question is not explained clearly, I've no experience in NLP, if this problem about word embedding is common basics in NLP, please tell me and I will check for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedding layer is just a trainable look-up table: it takes as input an integer index and returns as output the word embedding associated with that index:

```
index |                            word embeddings
=============================================================================
  0   |  word embedding for the word with index 0 (usually used for padding)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1   |  word embedding for the word with index 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2   |  word embedding for the word with index 2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .   |
  .   |
  .   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  N   |  word embedding for the word with index N
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It is trainable in that sense the embeddings values are not necessarily fixed and could be changed during training. The `input_dim` argument is actually the number of words (or more generally the number of distinct elements in the sequences). The `output_dim` argument specifies the dimension of each word embedding. For example in case of using `output_dim=100` each word embedding would be a vector of size 100. Further, since the input of an embedding layer is a sequence of integers (corresponding to the words in a sentence) therefore its output would have a shape of `(num_sequences, len_sequence, output_dim)`, i.e. for each integer in a sequence an embedding vector of size `output_dim` is returned.

As for the number of weights in an embedding layer it is very easy to calculate: there are `input_dim` unique indices and each index is associated with a word embedding of size `output_dim`. Therefore the number of weights in an embedding layer is `input_dim x ouput_dim`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it explains clear to me. By the way, I would like to ask is this embedding layer necessary for text classification tasks? And how could I train this weights? Does normal backpropagation works on this embedding layer?

Comment: Is the same input indices connection to output_dim have same weight( shared weight )?

Comment: @林彥良 It is not *necessary* in the sense that you can use other representations for your data instead like TF-IDF or bag-of-words or n-grams. However, word embeddings have shown to perform very well in NLP tasks. Training the weights is like training other layers and you don't need to do anything special about it. I could not understand your second comment. Please clarify it a bit. There is no weight sharing in an Embedding layer.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a list from which you get objects.

You do `object = myList[index]`

The embedding layer is similar to this list. But the "object" is a vector of trainable values.

So, your sequence contains indices to get vectors from the embedding.

Word 1 in sequence says: give me the vector for word 1
Word 2 says: give me the vector for word 2, and so on.

In practice, the weights will be a 2D matrix. You get rows from it based on the word indices passed in the sequence.

A sequence like `[wordIndex1, wordIndex2, wordIndex3]` will become `[wordVector1, wordVector2, wordVector3]`.