# Input to Keras layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I am having input sequences  with the following shape.

```
shape(1434, 185, 37)
```

There are total 1434 sequences, each with the length of 185 characters and the total number of unique characters is 37. So in a way, we have the vocab size as follows.

```
vocab_size=37
```

Now when I define my keras input to an embedded layer as follows,

```
user_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=((185,37)), name='Input_1')
user_vec = keras.layers.Flatten()(keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 50, input_length=185, name='Input_1_embed')(user_input))
```

I get the following error.

Error:

```
ValueError: "input_length" is 185, but received input has shape (None, 185, 37)
```

Now when I do the following, I don't get any error but I have doubt if it is right or not.

```
user_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=((185, )), name='Input_1')
user_vec = keras.layers.Flatten()(keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 50, input_length=185, name='Input_1_embed')(user_input))
```

Comment: Why do you need an embedding if your input sequences are one-hot encoded? Embedding take integer labels, not one-hot encoded ones.

Comment: I have edited the original question to exclude the one hot. Each sequence is two dimensional now. the first dimension is the sequence length and the second dimension shows the integer label based on the dictionary mapping of a specific character.

Comment: As @MatiasValdenegro mentioned, embedding layer takes integer values as inputs, not one-hot encoded vectors. That's why the second solution works. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53762684/2099607) for more explanation.

Comment: You should not edit the question to remove the problem, because now the question makes no sense, SO does not work like a forum. From the current question seems to be no problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments section, embedding layer takes integer values as input, not one-hot encoded vectors. That's why your second solution works but not the first one. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53762684/2099607) for more explanation.

However, if each timestep in your sequences is a vector of integers representing word indices (for example in each document you have 185 sentences where each sentence has 37 words), then you need to use [`TimeDistributed`](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#timedistributed) wrapper to apply the `Embedding` layer to each timestep:

```
user_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=((185,37)), name='Input_1')
emb_layer = keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 50, input_length=37, name='Input_1_embed')
user_vec = keras.layers.TimeDistributed(emb_layer)(user_input)
```

The shape of `user_vec` would be `(None, 185, 37, 50)`, i.e. an embedding vector of size 50 for each word in each timestep of each sequence.